# Android Google Map V2 screenshot in background

Tags: android, google-maps

I am creating an application in which, I need to send the bitmap of MAP screenshot via a WebService, when a GCM push notification arrives. So I actually need to capture the map from latitude and longitude that I have, in Background. I can't put that activity in front, there's no need of user to interact.

I have already developed the capture map logic, and it works, but for that I need an activity in front. But I wish to do all this in background.

Please Help.

Comment: How can it possible in background? and why you want do this in background?

Comment: I also know, it can't be executed in the background, but I need to find a way...! I need to send the location of B to A when he requests, along with a small map, not either I send the map as a byte array from B to A or when A receives it, He may load a map. but some logic is needed...! or if there's a way to capture it in background...

Comment: seriously you're requirement is very _HIGH_ but dont know how to archive this using GCM.